# Hosting multiple nodejs on same server/domain name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, hosting

I'm intending to host an online portfolio and I have several node.js projects I'd like to host.

So I'd like to host one project on domain.net/project1 and the other on domain.net/project2

Do I need to use a single nodejs process to do this, or is it possible to have each of my separate nodejs projects running independently?

Is it possible to assign a nodejs process to each subdomain?

Comment: In your case, Docker maybe a good choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach will be to host your NodeJS projects independently and then use the *domain(hosted and provided by platform) to Custom Sub-Domain(created by you) pointing* to point each of your projects to custom subdomains like project1.mydomain.com. This will provide you the flexibility to deploy your node applications on Heroku, AWS or any other hosting environment.

Thus you get freedom of choosing your own hosting platform and can have as many projects hosted as needed. I have attached an architecture diagram for the same and the link to the original draw.io document. Also please note that this is just a sample, and your design may vary as per your specific requirements

[image]

You can refer [this Arc diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMIPeaE2F1qw9s2bvHNvmy6vMEDKTTjh/view?usp=sharing) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx or apache http for host each project or create a path that contains sub paths for each one.

Here come references:

[Apache http](https://nitstorm.github.io/blog/apache-forward-reverse-proxies-1/)

[nginx hosting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)